# PHP Echo repeats after query

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm wanting to have an SQL Select statement that gets the values from the database and if there are any results then display a Form and the results in a dropdown menu.

Currently, it gets the values but the form echos the amount of times there are results. For example, if the query has 1 result it echos the form once. 2 results, echos the form twice and so on. I'm wanting the form to show up once but the drop down list to have all the results in.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks

[image with 2 results from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k24YN.png)

```
<?php
            include("conndetails.php");     
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            $sql    = "SELECT website_name FROM user_websites WHERE username='$_SESSION[user]'"; //Selects all the websites for the user that is logged in. 
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
              if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<h2>Download a website</h2>
          <form action="downloads.php" method="get">
          <select id="website_name" name="website_name">
          <option name="website_name">'. $row["website_name"]. '
          </option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Download">
          </form>
          <br>
          <hr>

          <h2>Upload to a website</h2>
          <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
          <p>Select file to upload:</p>
          <input type="file" name="zip_file" id="fileToUpload">
          <p>Select a website to upload to:</p>
          <select id="website_upload_name" name="website_upload_name">
          <option name="website_upload_name">'. $row["website_name"]. '
          </option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" style="position:relative; left: -1px;">
          </form>
          <br>
          <hr>';

             }}
    ?>
```

Comment: Then you need to move the form outside of the loop, and put the loop inside of the form.

Comment: Looks to me like this username has 2 records in the 'user_websites' table. You should probably have to only put the select options inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable `$options` and while returning data, add `<option>` to the variable.
Do not put all your `html`code inside the `while`.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   //Declare $options
   $options = '';


   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      //Adding <option> to the var $options
      $options .= '<option name="website_name">'. $row["website_name"]. '
          </option>';
    }



    //HTML once, first part
   $html = '<h2>Download a website</h2>
          <form action="downloads.php" method="get">
          <select id="website_name" name="website_name">';

   //Adding <option> to the <select>
   $html .= $options;

   //HTML once, second part
   $html .= '</select>
          <input type="submit" value="Download">
          </form>
          <br>
          <hr>

          <h2>Upload to a website</h2>
          <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
          <p>Select file to upload:</p>
          <input type="file" name="zip_file" id="fileToUpload">
          <p>Select a website to upload to:</p>
          <select id="website_upload_name" name="website_upload_name">'

    //Adding <option> to the second <select>
    $html .= $options;

    //HTML once, third part
    $html .= '</select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" style="position:relative; left: -1px;">
      </form>
      <br>
      <hr>';


  //Printing
  echo $html;


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it echoes as many time as the results found is because you've put the echo statement inside the while construct. If you want the echo to be shown only once when the condition of the if statement is verified move that echos outside the while and put the html code for options inside a variables which you'll build up within the while. Here I suppose both the combos needs to have the same options as from you original code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

$options = '';

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $options .= '<option name="website_name">'. $row["website_name"]. '</option>';    

  }

  echo '<h2>Download a website</h2>
        <form action="downloads.php" method="get">
          <select id="website_name" name="website_name">' . $options . '</select>
          <input type="submit" value="Download">
         </form>
         <br>
         <hr>

         <h2>Upload to a website</h2>
         <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
           <p>Select file to upload:</p>
           <input type="file" name="zip_file" id="fileToUpload">
           <p>Select a website to upload to:</p>
           <select id="website_upload_name" name="website_upload_name">' . $options . '</select>
           <br>
           <br>
           <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" style="position:relative; left: -1px;">
         </form>
         <br>
         <hr>';

}
```